# Access property of an object

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm new in Ionic with Angular and I have dynamic object that I want to access value on HTML `img src`

TS:

```
options = [
    {
      id: '0',
      icon: 'assets/icons/set-comparison.svg',
      text: 'Set Comparison'
    },
   ....
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of options" class="sidebar__content"   [ngClass]="{ 'active' : item === selectedMenuItem }">
          <button class="btn" (click)="selectedMenuItem = item">
            <img src="item.icon" class="sidebar__content custom__icon" alt="">
          </button>
        </li>
```

But when I debug it, instead get string route I get:

[image]

How can I access the property of my object correctly? Regards

Comment: img [attr.src]="item.icon". You forgot square brackets.

Comment: How should I search for this next time? I have no idea what is the concept of this @Gorynych

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Comment: really should be `[src]="item.icom"`. it's not only an attribute, is binding to a property. The sintax `[attr.name_atribute]="variable"` is for attributes that are not "properties" -e.g. the "data-attributes"

Comment: this would work  <img src="{{item.icon}}"

Comment: ooh, and what about events it should be `(click) = "item.action"`? @Eliseo

Comment: @Jesus, should be `(click)="item.action()"` (I write an answer to clarify this comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About use some like `(click)="item.action"`

The "events" are usually in the way `(click)="myfunction()"`. If you really has a function in item.action you should write

```
 (click)="item.action()"
```

But for this, you need that really the property "action" of your item was a function.

If "item" is an array of class

```
export class MyClass{
  prop1
  prop2
  action(){
    console.log(this.prop1+this.prop2)
  }
}
```

You should has some like

```
   //imagine this.service.getData return some like
   //[{prop1:"prop1",prop2:"prop2"},{prop1:"hello",prop2:"word"}]

   this.service.getData().subscribe((res:any[]=>{
      this.items=res.map(x=>{
         const obj=new MyClass()
         Object.assign(obj,x)
         return obj
      })
   })

   //or
   this.service.getData().pipe(map((res:any[])=>
      res.map(x=>{
         const obj=new MyClass()
         Object.assign(obj,x)
         return obj
      })).subscribe(res=>this.items=res)
```

But imagine you really received an array of object

```
 [{prop1:"prop1",prop2:"prop2",action:"action1"},
  {prop1:"hello",prop2:"word",action:action2}]
```

The best bet is write some like

```
 (click)="MyFunction(item.action)"
```

And in your .ts you has

```
myFunction(action:string)
{
    switch (action)
    {
       case "action1":
           this.action1() //<--here call to a function action1 defined in .ts
           break;
       case "action2":
           this.action2() //<--idem a function action2 defined in .ts
           break;
}
```

But you can also make some like

```
   this.service.getData().pipe(map((res:any[])=>
      res.map(x=>({...x,action:this[x.action]})
      })).subscribe(res=>this.items=res)
```

See that, in this case the property "action" of the first element is the function this["action1"] that we has defined in our .ts

Comment: I tried as your example but when I click the function respond with:  core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: ctx_r209.MyFunction is not a function

Comment: @Jesus, Angular is case-sensitive, that's MyFunction is different than myFunction -see the "M" and the "m"